# Dot Net Cisco Command Line Console Parser

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, parsing, network-programming, cisco

I'm Trying to write a Cisco Command Line Parser to have an automated Graphical User Interface replacement for the Cisco console output. I have been able to get the ping time using Regular Expressions from a ping output and graph it, but am now stuck with more detailed out put of other commands like "Show interfaces" command,
any ideas how I can parse the Show Interface command output and extract all the useful info which i need?

---

Here is a "Show Interfaces" out put example:

FastEthernet0/0 is up, line protocol is up 
  Hardware is MV96340 Ethernet, address is 0018.189d.1df0 (bia 0018.189d.1df0)
  Description: IP+ connection
  Internet address is 164.128.251.50/24
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 100000 Kbit/sec, DLY 100 usec, 
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  Full-duplex, 100Mb/s, 100BaseTX/FX
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input 00:00:00, output 00:00:00, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/3718/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 2000 bits/sec, 6 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 3000 bits/sec, 10 packets/sec
     152817108 packets input, 1043050554 bytes
     Received 77347880 broadcasts (67140888 IP multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 3351 throttles
     381823 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 381823 ignored
     0 watchdog
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
 --More--              99065802 packets output, 440637782 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 2 interface resets
     300246 unknown protocol drops
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
FastEthernet0/1 is administratively down, line protocol is down 
  Hardware is MV96340 Ethernet, address is 0018.189d.1df1 (bia 0018.189d.1df1)
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 100000 Kbit/sec, DLY 100 usec, 
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  Auto-duplex, Auto Speed, 100BaseTX/FX
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input never, output never, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     0 packets input, 0 bytes
     Received 0 broadcasts (0 IP multicasts)
 --More--              0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
 --More--              0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 watchdog
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     0 packets output, 0 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
     0 unknown protocol drops
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
Tunnel0 is up, line protocol is up 
  Hardware is Tunnel
  Interface is unnumbered. Using address of FastEthernet0/0 (164.128.251.50)
  MTU 17912 bytes, BW 100 Kbit/sec, DLY 50000 usec, 
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation TUNNEL, loopback not set
  Keepalive not set
  Tunnel source 164.128.251.50 (FastEthernet0/0), destination 164.128.32.1
   Tunnel Subblocks:
      src-track:
         Tunnel0 source tracking subblock associated with FastEthernet0/0
          Set of tunnels with source FastEthernet0/0, 1 member (includes iterators), on interface 
  Tunnel protocol/transport PIM/IPv4
 --More--           Tunnel TOS/Traffic Class 0xC0,  Tunnel TTL 255
 --More--           Tunnel transport MTU 1472 bytes
  Tunnel is transmit only
  Tunnel transmit bandwidth 8000 (kbps)
  Tunnel receive bandwidth 8000 (kbps)
  Last input never, output 28w1d, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/0 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     0 packets input, 0 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 0 broadcasts (0 IP multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
     44 packets output, 2464 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
     0 unknown protocol drops
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
Virtual-Access1 is up, line protocol is up 
  Hardware is Virtual Access interface
  Description: ***Internally created by SSLVPN context TEST***
  MTU 1406 bytes, BW 100000 Kbit/sec, DLY 100000 usec, 
 --More--              reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
 --More--           Encapsulation SSL
  Internal vaccess
  Vaccess status 0x0, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  DTR is pulsed for 5 seconds on reset
  Last input never, output never, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters 29w5d
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     0 packets input, 0 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 0 broadcasts (0 IP multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
     0 packets output, 0 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
     0 unknown protocol drops
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
     0 carrier transitions

Interface_Long_Split = Regex.Split(Result_Long, "(POS[0-9]*/[0-9]*/[0-9]*)|(POS[0-9]*/[0-9]*)|(GigabitEthernet[0-9]/[0-9])|(FastEthernet[0-9]/[0-9]*)")
            Dim count As Integer = 0
            For i = 0 To Interface_Long_Split.Length
                If Regex.IsMatch(Interface_Long_Split(i), "(POS[0-9]*/[0-9]*/[0-9]*)|(POS[0-9]*/[0-9]*)|(GigabitEthernet[0-9]/[0-9])|(FastEthernet[0-9]/[0-9]*)") = True Then
                    ReDim Preserve Interfaces_List(count)
                    Interfaces_List(count) = Interface_Long_Split(i)
                    count = count + 1
                End If

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: well I'm making a telnet session to the router and storing the above in a string named result_long then using the regular expressions function try to parse it. I added the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imho you are probably on a hiding to nothing.

you could try parsing those complex outputs a line at a time rather than as one big blob.